# How to display an additional window with a gtk C query?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I would like a window to appear when I start a program in C using GTK+ 3.0, asking for a number to be entered, once entered this window closes and the main window opens, where the actual program takes place using the parameter specified by the user. I have no idea how to do this, I would appreciate any help.

```
int main( int argc,char *argv[] ){
gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
GtkWidget *window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Sudoku");
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),8);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
GtkWidget *box1=gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),box1);
CreateBoard(box1);            //my function                          
CreateControl(box1);          //my function                           
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
srand(time(NULL));
StartGame();                  //my function                                                         
gtk_main();
return 0;
}
```

Above is my main function, I create the main window in it. Using which functions from GTK can I create another window which is displayed before the main one?

Comment: What did you try? Please show your code.

Comment: I'm making a Sudoku game and I'm already quite advanced, I have many lines of code in a couple of modules (so I'm not sure if there's any point in posting my code), but I'd like it to be up to the user to decide how many randomly distributed numbers to start the game with. And I came up with the idea that when the program is turned on, it will display a window into which the user can enter a number, if at all possible.

Comment: Then just show a [mre] of the problematic part